# Name of the font

Tags: fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture)

Can anyone tell me the **name of the font** encoded in the following page

- http://www.sanskritweb.net/yajurveda/yv-ta.pdf
- Next, how can I use this font using the "Polyglossia" package.
- What are the different Sanskrit font's available at "Polyglossia" package. I only know of Nakula and Sahadeva. Can the default font (that is the output font after processing with the devnag pre-processor) of the devanagari package be brought as the output while using the polyglossia package.

Comment: I believe that the PDF file should ahve the font info, but if not, you can try: [WhatTheFont](http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/)

Comment: To answer the third question, see the following discussion on the XeTeX mailing list: [Devanagari fonts](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.xetex/20484)

Comment: You keep referring to the `polyglossia` package as loading or otherwise managing fonts. Being admittedly a bit pedantic about this, it's actually the `fontspec` package that performs these jobs.

Comment: Please only ask one question per post. This way, other users with similar problems can find old questions more easily. Since your first question is answered here, I suggest you remove questions 2 and 3 from this post. Also, please don't forget to upvote answers that helped you (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 3):

The `Document Properties` of the referenced file shows:

[image]

Comment: Do you were those font's can be found. I searched in google, but couldn't locate it. Moreover any idea of how one uses the fonts in XeLaTeX

Comment: Sorry, have not worked much with different fonts.  Did Alan Munn's comment above provide the answer?

Comment: Sorry nothing there is nothing on that link

Comment: @AlanMunn: Seems that the link you pointed to does not have much info on the matter.